# how to check if an anchor tag is clicked or not in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html code.

```
               <div class="main_links cf" id="main_link">
                    <a class="est_btn" id="#electric">
                        <img src="images/electric.png" alt="" />
                        <span>Electric</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="est_btn" id="#gas">
                        <img src="images/gas.png" alt="" />
                        <span>Gas</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="est_btn" id="#oil">
                        <img src="images/oil.png" alt="" />
                        <span>Oil</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="est_btn" id="#propane">
                        <img src="images/propane.png" alt="" />
                        <span>Propane</span>
                    </a>

                </div>
```

Now i want atleast one of these anchor tags should be clicked.
Can anyone tell me how it can be done with jquery ?

Comment: I dont get it, you want to click a anchor tag using jQuery or to listen to which anchor tag is clicked in the given list ?

Comment: Actually this is some type of validation.User will not proceed untill he clicks one of anchor tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class to store the clicked state

```
var $links = $('#main_link .est_btn').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});

//for test
$('button').click(function () {
    if ($links.is('.clicked')) {
        alert('clicked')
    } else {
        alert('not')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z2AsF/)

If you want to allow the user to select/unselect an item the use `toggleClass()` instead of `addClass()`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z2AsF/)

Comment: Hey you are Genius!. Your answer is 101% correct and it solved my problem. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$( ".est_btn" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Clicked" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".est_btn").click(function () {
   //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".est_btn" ).click(function() {
    console.log("clicked Anchor Id =" + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```